# Can you really upgrade the RAM in the M1 2020 Mac Mini to 64 Gigs?

Tags: upgrade, memory, mac-mini, apple-silicon

I think this sites claims to sell Mac Mini 2020 M1 Ram Upgrades to 64gb https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/apple/mac-mini-%282020%29

--but--

Everymac.com and the Verge.com both claim the RAM limit is 16gb and is not upgradable.  I don’t understand the confusion from these sites or am looking at old articles, not finding the correct links for new M1 Macs.

Can the M1 Macs get aftermarket RAM upgrades?

Comment: Apple altered the stock configurations (e.g. amount of storage, RAM, etc) of the 2018 Mini in 2020, leading to some people calling it the "2020 Mini".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No RAM upgrade - you would need to reflow new processor board or be skilled enough to rework the one you have.

RAM Memory on the [Apple Silicon M1 Processor is integral to system package “chip” that’s mounted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) as one unit to the logic board. [There is no slot or place to add memory on the M1 based Air, Pro or Mini](https://www.macworld.com/article/234843/m1-macs-memory-isnt-what-it-used-to-be.html). The [SSD chips have separate placement on the logic board](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hczcaGX62S0) from the Processor board. Everything is soldered to the logic board for Apple Silicon Minis.

I would not mistake an 8 GB RAM Air, Pro or Mini for anything but a beast of a workstation for most tasks. Real world benchmarks are showing them completing work dramatically faster than 12 core Mac Pro with 32 GB of RAM.

- https://twitter.com/cocoalabs/status/1330199233090244615

Pick any ten apps you want to start and race the entry level Air with any Mac of your choosing - iMac Pro, Mac Pro, or an 8 core MacBook Pro - there are only few specialized tasks where the Air is slower.

The 2020 Intel mini is still available and that’s what crucial and others are selling memory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116750/discussion-on-answer-by-bmike-can-you-really-upgrade-the-ram-in-the-m1-2020-mac).

Answer (score 1):

Note there is an Intel Mac mini 2020 https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/buy-mac/mac-mini/3.0ghz-intel-core-i5-6-core-processor-with-intel-uhd-graphics-630-512gb#
which has 8gb RAM

So the crucial description is correct for intel processors, incorrect for M1 based Minis.